# SPO Modern List/Form: Prevent user from adding/overwriting a column value if already populated

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

Using JSON, I am looking for a way to prevent a user from adding/overwriting a new column value if that column is already populated with a value.

I used to use jQuery in SP2013 but I'm seeking ways to accomplish similar functions using JSON.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native functionality available using JSON formatting for your requirements to prevent users from changing value.

You can show/hide fields from list forms using conditional formula but you cannot make those non-editable.

**Documentation**: [Show or hide columns in a list or library form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide)

---

**Workaround**:

You have to customize the list form using Power Apps to show fields on list for and make those non-editable on list form at the same time.

Comment: Thank you @Ganesh. I sent a message to you via your wordpress site. :-)

Comment: Thanks for contacting. I checked your code and found that it is using `"elmType": "input",` which is not supported by JSON formatting, check [elmType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#elmtype). Also, I tried using the JSON you shared and it does not work as suspected.

Comment: Hi @ChasEpes, does above answer help you in any way?